# Can I say the integer solution of this equation is unique?

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations, integers

I want to solve the equation $\frac{y!}{(x-2)!(y-x)!}=\frac{1340!}{659!\times679!}$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I think it is natural to say $(x,y)=(681,1340)$ and $(x,y)=(661,1340)$ are desired solutions.
But can I assure that there are no other solutions?
I tried MATLAB and Wolframalpha, but they stop working due to the huge number $\frac{1340!}{659!\times679!}$.
Would you help me?

Comment: How do you define $n!$ for negative integers? Or did you mean to restrict to $y\geq x\geq2$?

Comment: Because $1327$ is prime, for any solution $(x,y)$ you must have $y\geq1327$.

Comment: You cannot define $n!$ for negative $n$, but you can actually define ${m \choose n}$ for negative $n$. By using Weierstrass's definition of gamma function instead of factorial, you can check it is $0$ for $m>0$ and $n<0$ (also $n>m$).

Comment: Also $\frac{y!}{(x-2)!(y-x)!}=y(y-1)\tbinom{y-2}{x-2}$, so certainly $y(y-1)$ divides $\frac{1340!}{659!\times679!}$. This leaves 'just' finitely many $y$ to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COMMENT.-Note that this is a type of problem formed as follows: if $a + b + 2 = c$ then the equation $$\frac{y!}{(x-2)!(y-x)!}=\frac{c!}{a!b!}$$ has the obvious two solutions $ x = a + 2 $ and $ x = b + 2 $ with $ y = c $ in both cases.

Take $(a,b,c)=(659,679,1340)$ and note that we have for the fixed value $c=1340$ all the possibilities $\dfrac{1340!}{(a+2)!(1338-a)!}$ corresponding to $x=a+2$ with many admissible values of $a$.

Because of all these possible values are binomial coefficients  in developing $(x+1)^{1340}$ and these are two equal (*for the even $1340$ there is one non repeated which is
$\binom{1340}{670}$*) it follows that the two given solutions, $x=661$ and $x=681$  are the only ones $\color{red}{\text{ assuming that } y=1340}$.

I don't know if proving $y$ is necessarily equal to $1340$ is easy or difficult (I feel it is not hard and in any case one must have $1327\le y\le1361$ where $1327$ and $1361$ are consecutive primes).

Comment: Thank you for brilliant insight. But can I ask why $y$ should be in $[1327,1361]$?

Comment: @OKW1124: You have $a!b!y!=c!(x-2)!(y-x)!$ so the prime $1327$ should divide $c!$ (note that $x\le y$ because factorial is not defined for negative integers). If $y\gt c$ then the prime factor $1361$ does not divide $RHS$. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Now it is much more clear! But I am not certain about one thing: If $y=1361$, LHS contains $1361$ as its factor but RHS does not. So it would be better to say $1327 \leq y < 1361$. Am I right?

Comment: @okw1124: That's right. You can try to prove the unicity of solution with small values of the constant $c$ which could inspire you for the value $c=1340$